# Nginx proxy manager server reachability test fails for SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt

I have my domain from `domains.google.com`. Let's say it's `mydomainname.com`

I set DNS to my desired IP address. On my router, I forwarded port `80` to my computer's `80` and `443` to my computer's `443`. To confirm it's publicly available, I used different connections and devices and I can access `mydomainname.com` with no problem.

Then I used a `docker-compose.yml` file as described in [their website](https://nginxproxymanager.com/setup/#using-mysql-mariadb-database).

Current `latest` points to `v2.9.18`

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '81:81'
    volumes:
      - ./data/:/data
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
```

Now, on SSL Certificates tab, while adding an SSL Certificate, testing server reachability fails all the time with the following error:

```
mydomainname.com: There is no server available at this domain.
Please make sure your domain exists and points to the IP where your NPM
instance is running and if necessary port 80 is forwarded in your router.
```

What might be the issue?